# Protecting route using firebase

Tags: firebase, express, firebase-authentication

I've provided code below in which a user can be redirected to dashboard page by successful authentication by firebase.But anyone can access dashboard page without authentication.Now how can I protect this dashboard page?

Note:I'm using HTML,CSS and JS as frontend and Node.js backend.

```
app.all('/login',(req,res)=>{
    email=req.body.email;
    password=req.body.password;
    var prom=firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password);
    prom.then((creds)=>{
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
    },(err)=>{
        res.redirect('/error');
    });

});
```

Expected output:

If anyone tries to access dashboard page without authentication then he must redirect to error page.

Comment: I think this is not the correct way to handle this situation. What you need to do is log user in with his credentials which will return an access token take that access token and send it to your route every time you try to access a server resource.

Comment: I don't know much about these tokens.I'm just noobie in firebase.I've read about tokens in firebase docs but I'm not able understand.Could you please provide me any source to learn about these tokens.